# How to specify absolute path within logback.xml?

Tags: java, logback

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration debug="true">
    <include resource="/opt/logback/logback_mobile.xml"></include>
</configuration>
```

> Could not find resource corresponding to [/opt/logback/logback_mobile.xml]

But the file does exist.

How can I specify an absolute path within `logback.xml`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three options when including a resource within a logback.xml file:

> **As a file**:
>
> To include a file use the file attribute. You can use ***relative*** paths but note that the current directory is defined by the application and is not necessarily related to the path of the configuration file.
>
> **As a resource:**
>
> To include a resource, i.e a file found on the class path, use the resource attribute.
> `<include resource="includedConfig.xml"/>`
>
> **As a URL:**
>
> To include the contents of a URL use the url attribute.
> `<include url="http://some.host.com/includedConfig.xml"/>`

From the [docs](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html).

So, you can use a file path relative to where the application is running or you can use a classpath reference or you can use a URL buut absolute file paths are not supported.

To include this file: `/opt/logback/logback_mobile.xml` I think your options are:

- Use a relative reference, assuming your application is running from `/opt/app/myservice` then your include declaration would be: `<include resource="../../logback/logback_mobile.xml"></include>`.
- Include `/opt/logback/` on your application's classpath and then change the include declaration to `<include resource="logback_mobile.xml"></include>`.
- Serve `logback_mobile.xml` from a web server and then include it by URL.